# How to use named binds with bulk inserts (executemany) in cx_Oracle from pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, cx-oracle

I am uncertain on how to bulk insert to Oracle from Python 3 using named bind-variables, when source-data is in a Pandas Dataframe. The code below shows my attempt. With unnamed binds, it is pretty easy, but errorprone, as the order of binds need to be the same as columns in the Dataframe.

```
    "Named pandas binds with cursor.executemany in cx_oracle, how ?"
    import pandas as pd
    import cx_Oracle
    # create table t( a number, b varchar2 (20 char));
    df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': [1, 2], 'b': ["Dog", "Cat"]})
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect('/@DB')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    # Bulk insert, numbered binds work
    cur.execute("truncate table t")
    cur.executemany("insert into t (a, b) values (:1, :2)", df.values.tolist())
    print(pd.read_sql("select a, b from t", con=conn))
    # Insert, named binds work
    cur.execute("truncate table t")
    cur.execute("insert into t (a, b) values (:cc, :dd)", dd="Donkey", cc=1)
    print(pd.read_sql("select a, b from t", con=conn))
    # Bulk insert, named binds do not work
    cur.execute("truncate table t")
    cur.executemany("insert into t (a, b) values (:cc, :dd)", dd=df['b'].values.tolist(), cc=df['a'].values.tolist())
    # TypeError: Required argument 'parameters' (pos 2) not found
    print(pd.read_sql("select a, b from t", con=conn))
    #
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

Niels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you intend to use named bind variables you will need to do the following instead:

```
[{"a" : 1, "b" : "Dog"}, {"a" : 2, "b" : "Cat"}]
```

In other words you need to create a list of dictionaries instead of a list of lists.

Answer (score 1):

Anthony is, of course, right. The following code (modified from my original question) demonstrates this. Note that the named binds variables :b, :a are in reverse order from the columns in the dataframe and are matched even so (which illustrates the primary reason that I want named binds, which is to defend against relying on the order of binds and dataframe columns being the same)

Thank you.

```
"""
Named cx_Oracle bind variables with cursor.executemany and pandas dataframe as input
The trick is to convert the dataframe to a list of dictionaries
"""
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
# create table t(a number, b varchar2 (20 char));
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': [1, 2], 'b': ["Dog", "Cat"]})
print(df.to_dict('records'))
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('/@DB')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.executemany("insert into t (b, a) values (:b, :a)", df.to_dict('records'))
print(pd.read_sql("select a, b from t", con=conn))
conn.rollback()
cur.close()
conn.close()
# Output
#[{'a': 1, 'b': 'Dog'}, {'a': 2, 'b': 'Cat'}]
#   A    B
# 0  1  Dog
# 1  2  Cat
```